# ternary operator in php sets variable wrong unless there are brackets

Tags: php, ternary-operator

it seems a bit odd how the ternary operator works in php, can someone shed light?

```
$z = 'testval';
$x = 'hello ' . isset($z) ? $z : ' notfound';

var_dump($x);  //testval
```

this results in the expected result:

```
$z = 'testval';
$x = 'hello ' . (isset($z) ? $z : ' notfound');

var_dump($x); //returns hello testval
```

Comment: I'd say you're focusing on the wrong operator. The ternary is doing just fine, it's the concatenation operator that is showing a difference

Comment: its about operator precedence.

Comment: Think of the first example like this ~ `$x = ('hello' . isset($z)) ? $z : ' notfound'`

Comment: add it as answer phil